# Issue with geny motion in android studio. can't get Virtual device to appear in AVD manager

Tags: android-studio, genymotion, android-virtual-device

first I create Motorola moto X vitual device tageting API 4.2.2 in android. this device was created successfully in geny motion. I then run this virtual device to see if it is operating correctly.  Once started I keep getting this error message regardless of what i do

"Genymotion version and virtual device version do not match

Genmotion 2.2.2
Virtual Device 1.0.0

you should update you virtual device or create a new one to enjoy the new features"???

I dont have a clue how to update the virtual device? moreover I wasn't given the option to set the device when creating the device. just to choose target version of android. Can anybody guide me through how to do this? Also the UPDATE button cant be selected so i have to just select continue.

After this I change settings/ADB on the virtual device to point to the android sdk located at "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-studio/sdk".

then I app the genymotion plugin to the list of plugins in settings. and following this I add the path location of the genymotion folder also in settings under IDE settings/ Genymotion and the path being "C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion"

When I open AVD manager the genymotion emulator is not visible so I cant select it to run my applications. I have tried setting "show chooser Dialog" in Run/debug configuration and also setting the correct sdk for the virtual device like I said earlier. If anyone can help me out with this I would be grateful otherwise It looks like i will have to use the standard emulator which is SH*t :) .hopefully this question can help someone in the future also. thanks in advance!

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb

make sure you use same sdk for both android studio and genymotion!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your virtual device is very old. 
If you use the free license you need to remove this old device and create a new one thanks to the "add" button on the Genymotion program.

Then launch the newly created virtual device, you should not see the `Genymotion version and virtual device version do not match` popup any more. 
If it still chows up, send a report to the [Genymotion support](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/).

Concerning the AVD manager problem. Genymotion devices are not supposed to be added to this interface. To launch a Genymotion virtual device you can whether:

- Open the Eclipse Genymotion plugin you already installed and configure (the small pink genymotion icon on the tool bar)
- Or open the Genymotion program that will show you all the devices you already created. And where you can create new virtual devices.

When a device is launched, you can then debug on it easily, it is considered as any device connected to ADB like a physical device you plug on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the craziest tricks I've seen work (I know it sounds crazy but try it) is to stretch the columns in the device column when you go to run and it shows you no devices, device magically appears in list.