# Android Studio - Lollipop, ADB, & Genymotion issues: Devices won't show up. "adb server is out of date. killing..."

Tags: android, adb, genymotion, android-5.0-lollipop

---

**Update (11/10/14): Genymotion has released 2.3.1 which fixes this issue. https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/changelog/#231**

---

Update (10/21/14): Genymotion replied to my support email and indicated the solution recommended by @plackemacher below is the suggested fix at the moment. They are aware of the issue.

---

Since upgrading to Lollipop, I'm having adb issues when using a Genymotion emulator. Devices don't show up in Android Studio, and I've also gotten the following error when trying to run `adb devices`:

```
$ adb devices

adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the Lollipop upgrade or coincidence.

**Edit/update**:

Per Chris Satton's comment, I investigated if multiple adb processes were running (`ps aux | grep adb`), and it looks like it's a Genymotion conflict(?). It looks to include its own version of adb.

> greg      72550   0.0  0.0   611164   1508   ??  S     4:14PM
> 0:00.02
> /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb
> -s 192.168.56.102:5555 shell
>
> greg      72523   0.0  0.0   635956   2296   ??  S     4:14PM   0:00.02 adb -P 5037 fork-server server

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Try running this:

```
killall -9 adb
```

That should remove all running traces of the daemon

**Edit: Best solution below**

This issue may be `adb` incompatibility with the newest version of the platform SDK. The best solution for this issue with Genymotion is to set the Android SDK within Genymotion to your location. This can be found within the Settings page.

[image: Genymotion Settings window]

Comment: Also make sure there aren't multiple copies of ADB on the development machine.

Comment: Looks like this may be a problem with genymotion. I'm going to update my question with more details

Comment: Genymotion must have an old version of adb packaged. Thanks!

Comment: Or just set Android sdk path instead using default Genymotion adb.

Comment: genymotion installed as application, mac os 10.10 restart -> settings reset. I must set it up manually after each restart. :(

Comment: @ChrisStratton How can I ensure that there is just one copy of ADB? When I see the running processes through Task Manager, I see two instances of adb.exe running every time.

Comment: I was having an issue with NativeScript where the Genymotion device(s) were not being detected - I kept getting errors saying the daemon could not be started because the connection was refused. Changing the Genymotion adb settings resolved this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that I have installed adb tools and fastboot using this command

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

From repository, so in this case this executables goes to the `/usr/bin/` directory in order that you can use it system-wide (`$PATH` variable).

In addition, I am running android studio with genymotion configured like in the answer above.

So when I was trying to acces adb (`adb shell` in my case) it was trying to start another copy of adb process (server) and bind to default port, so the problem was here.

I have just uninstalled the `android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot` and added the path to my `Android SDK` to the `$PATH` variable

Answer (score 2):

Using genymotion on ubuntu.

My solution was to actually use the binary instead of the PATH'd adb.

`~/genymotion/tools/abd reboot`

Also I have the custom SDK in genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me finally and what I think is hastle free is that you simply run the adb commands directly from `platform-tools` folder. For example, use `./adb devices` to view the devices.
I also changed genymotion's SDK to android's default SDK but I'm not sure if it won't work without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think ,if you want to use **adb** its better to use android studio emulator and test what you want, after you can use Genymotion

Answer (score -1):

None of solutions helped for Ubuntu.
Just drag .apk file onto Genymotion device's screen and app will be installed.

Ubuntu 15.04, Genymotion 2.5.2

Comment: we are finding the adb issues, not talking about the installation of apk.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer did not work for me, although the idea did, just with a different command:

```
pkill adb
```

I'm running ubuntu MATE 1.8.2 and Genymotion 2.6.

Answer (score -2):

Add the Android SDK to the `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score -2):

I just used ./adb reboot on Android/Sdk/platform-tools/