# Android Studio: ADB not responding error, and two instances of adb.exe are simultaneously running

Tags: ide, android-studio, adb, genymotion

I am constantly getting the famous "*ADB not responding. You can wait more,or kill“abd.exe” process manually and click 'Restart'*" error, and when I run the Windows Task Manager to kill the process, I can see two instances of `adb.exe` running simultaneously.

I have Eclipse and Android Studio installed and both use the same SDK, if that matters.

Now when I kill both the instances of the `adb.exe` the process, and then restart adb by `adb start-service` from command prompt and get the message something like `deamon started successfully.

But then when I start Android Studio again, I face the same problem.

**So any suggestions for me? Does two processes of `adb.exe` have something to do with this?**

PS I am trying to use genymotion as the simulator, if that matters. And I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

[image: Windows Task Manager]

Comment: Getting the same problem after latest SDK updates. Didn't find any official response or confirmation though

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by AAverin, take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431991/2046423

You just need to change the adb settings (user android-sdk in place of genymotion)

Answer (score -1):

You need to restart your computer once
After this, the problem will be solved