# ADB not responding in Android Studio 1.1 Beta4

Tags: android, android-studio

I've used to date without any problems from Android Studio, But today I wanted to use this error to the Android Studio.
I used to run a virtual machine from GenyMontion
I also refer to the following link but could not solve my issue : 
[Click to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431972/android-studio-lollipop-adb-genymotion-issues-devices-wont-show-up-adb/26431991#26431991)

Error Image : 
[Click to see](http://tellfa.com/images/Tellfa_image/ADB_error.JPG)

please help me

Comment: Did you try restarting adb? Why are you using the beta version when 1.1 has been released?

Comment: @mattm : Yes button to restart it, but I did not react. 1.1 stable version has been released

Comment: Just run gradlew via command line. `gradlew installDebug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this exact problem each time I restart Android Studio or Genymotion during the day. The adb kill/start has no effect and linking Genymotion to the android SDK tools has no effect.

For me, the best way to get back to coding/development is to:
1) Start up another virtual device
2) Run Debug and verify the device shows up
3) Kill it off
4) Start up the virtual device I really wanted

And miraculously the device I REALLY want shows up in "Choose Device, Choose a running device" dialog

Frustrating, but the workaround works.